# getview() method of baseadapter not called in fragment

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-fragments

I am using the Fragment to display the list. ListAdapter uses Baseadapter. It returns getcount greater than 0 but still not called getview() method.

Also I was set adapter in fragment and called listadapter like :

```
mListAdapter = new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), data, enum);
sList.setAdapter(mListAdapter); 
mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Adapter gets called without a problem and `GetCount()` also called but 
`GetView()` doesn't get called.

ListAdapter :

```
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<WatchVO> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context mcontext;
private ENUM enum;

public String TAG = "MyListAdapter";


public MyListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<WatchVO> data,
        ENUM enum) {
   // super(context,0,data);

    this.mcontext = context;
    this.data = data;
    this.enum = enum;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public int getCount() { Log.d(TAG,"count"+data.size());
    if (data.size()<=0)
        return 1;
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    Log.d(TAG,"getitem"+data.get(position));
    return data.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            Log.d(TAG,""+parent +"pos" + position);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_scripts,parent,false);
            holder.tableRow = (TableRow) convertView.findViewById(R.id.table_row_item);
            holder.priceChangeContainer = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.color_container_red_green);
            holder.sName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sName);
            holder.sPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sMRP);
            holder.sPriceChange = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sPrice);
            holder.sPricePercentageChange = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sPriceChange);
            holder.sVolume = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sVolume);

            holder.sName.setText(data.get(position).getSName());
            holder.sPrice.setText(data.get(position).getSMRP());
            holder.sPriceChange.setText(data.get(position).getSChange());
            holder.sPricePercentageChange.setText(data.get(position).getSPercentageChange());


            convertView.setTag(holder);
     }
    else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
    return convertView;
}
public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView sName, sPrice, sPriceChange, sPricePercentageChange, sVolume;
    public LinearLayout priceChangeContainer;
    public TableRow tableRow;
}
}
```

Comment: hey.. it will calls for one time. It won't call for later times. Because you are checking everytime for convertView == null .Once you assigned your view to convertview then convertview is not null. So your condition will not work.

Answer (score 0):

your are passing wrong adapter to listView. change your code

```
mListAdapter = new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), data, enum); 
sList.setAdapter(marketMoversListAdapter); 

mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

to

```
mListAdapter = new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), data, enum); 
sList.setAdapter(mListAdapter); 

mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: print log outside if in getView. and check is log printing or not.

Comment: Try this also still it not called  the getView() method. :(

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like below :

```
 if (convertView == null) {
             convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_scripts,null);
        tableRow = (TableRow) convertView.findViewById(R.id.table_row_item);
        priceChangeContainer = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.color_container_red_green);
        sName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sName);
        sPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sMRP);
        sPriceChange = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sPrice);
        sageChange = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sChange);
        sVolume = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sVolume);

        sName.setText(data.get(position).getSName());
        sPrice.setText(data.get(position).getSMRP());
        sChange.setText(data.get(position).getSChange());
        sChange.setText(data.get(position).getSChange());
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        return convertView;
```

Comment: i do the changes. but my problem not solved. I agree only one time getview() method called. but one time also getview() not called. Thanks for replay.

Comment: please post your full adapter class ?

Comment: uncomment super method  " // super(context,0,data);"